# Gulp task multiple and shared scss files

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

In my current project, I have three main .scss files. Each one of them imports a lot of partials files, and sometimes, a partial files is imported in two or three of the main files.

For example: I have a `main.scss` and a `nl-main.scss` files. `main.scss` imports the partials `_page.scss` and `_post.scss`. `nl-main.scss` imports `_title.scss` and `_post.scss`. Here is my current folder structure:

```
css
   modules
      _page.scss
      _post.scss
      _title.scss
   main.scss
   nl-main.scss
```

And here is my current `gulpfile.js` setup:

```
var gulp = require( 'gulp' ),
        sass = require( 'gulp-sass' ),
        autoprefixer = require( 'gulp-autoprefixer' ),
        minifycss = require( 'gulp-minify-css' ),
        uglify = require( 'gulp-uglify' ),
        rename = require( 'gulp-rename' ),
        clean = require( 'gulp-clean' ),
        concat = require( 'gulp-concat' ),
        plumber = require( 'gulp-plumber' ),
        notify = require( 'gulp-notify' ),
        projectTitle = 'Project Name';

// styles task
gulp.task( 'styles', function() {
    return gulp.src( 'src/css/main.scss' )
        .pipe( plumber() )
        .pipe( sass({ paths: ['src/css/'] }) )
        .pipe( notify( {
        title: projectTitle,
        message: 'File: <%= file.relative %> was compiled!'
        } ) )
        .pipe( autoprefixer( 'last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4' ) )
        .pipe( gulp.dest( 'dist/assets/css' ) )
        .pipe( rename( { suffix: '.min' } ) )
        .pipe( minifycss() )
        .pipe( gulp.dest( 'dist/assets/css' ) )
        .pipe( notify( {
        title: projectTitle,
        message: 'Minified file: <%= file.relative %> was created / updated!'
        } ) )
} );

// styles task - not logged
gulp.task( 'nl-styles', function() {
    return gulp.src( 'src/css/nl-main.scss' )
        .pipe( plumber() )
        .pipe( sass({ paths: ['src/css/'] }) )
        .pipe( notify( {
        title: projectTitle,
        message: 'File: <%= file.relative %> was compiled!'
        } ) )
        .pipe( autoprefixer( 'last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4' ) )
        .pipe( gulp.dest( 'dist/assets/css' ) )
        .pipe( rename( { suffix: '.min' } ) )
        .pipe( minifycss() )
        .pipe( gulp.dest( 'dist/assets/css' ) )
        .pipe( notify( {
        title: projectTitle,
        message: 'Minified file: <%= file.relative %> was created / updated!'
        } ) )
} );

// watch task
gulp.task( 'watch', function() {

    // Watch .scss files
    gulp.watch( 'src/css/**/*.scss', [ 'styles', 'nl-styles' ] );

});
```

But, when I run `gulp watch`, only the `nl-styles` task runs.

My question is what's the best approach to make this work and runs both the tasks (or only one task, if no shared partials are modified)? Any tips on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

May it's a problem with the parallel tasks. So why you don't use only one task? Try this:

```
// styles task
gulp.task( 'styles', function() {
    return gulp.src( 'src/css/*.scss' )
        .pipe( plumber() )
        .pipe( sass({ paths: ['src/css/'] }) )
        .pipe( notify( {
        title: projectTitle,
            message: 'File: <%= file.relative %> was compiled!'
        } ) )
        .pipe( autoprefixer( 'last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4' ) )
        .pipe( gulp.dest( 'dist/assets/css' ) )
        .pipe( rename( { suffix: '.min' } ) )
        .pipe( minifycss() )
        .pipe( gulp.dest( 'dist/assets/css' ) )
        .pipe( notify( {
        title: projectTitle,
        message: 'Minified file: <%= file.relative %> was created / updated!'
        } ) )
} );
```

All scss files will be compiled to css and your gulpfile is much clearer.